# How to write in each line of system of equations after a vertical line

Tags: equations, line, vertical

So I have made a system of equations and put the vertical line after it:
[image]

[image]

But I need to write in each line of system after that vertical line, it should look  something lake that:[image]
I don't know how to do it, help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution with two systemes

```
\documentclass[border=15]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
$\systeme{2x_1 + 3x_2 - 4x_3 - 2x_4 = 3,
2x_1 +  x_2 -  x_3 - 3x_4 = 2,
2x_1        +  x_3 - 7x_4 = 3,
       2x_2 - 3x_3 +  x_4 = 1}
\sysdelim|.\systeme{,\-I,\-I,}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extra column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\bigvrule}{%
  \smash{%
    \vrule height 1.3\normalbaselineskip depth 0.7\normalbaselineskip width 0.4pt
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\syscodeextracol{\enspace}{}
\systeme{
   x_1+3x_2-4x_3-2x_4=3  @ \vrule,
  2x_1+ x_2- x_3-3x_4=2  @ \bigvrule\;$-I$,
  2x_1+      x_3-7x_4=3  @ \bigvrule\;$-I$,
       2x_2-3x_3+ x_4=1  @ \vrule
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

It's a bit of a hack: the middle rules are higher and deeper so they overlap the first and last.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some `\rlap`s trailed by a `\hphantom` do the trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\syscodeextracol{\enspace}{}
\sysdelim\{|
ZZ\systeme{
   x_1+3x_2-4x_3-2x_4=3,
  2x_1+ x_2- x_3-3x_4=2 @\rlap{\hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{-I}$}},
  2x_1+      x_3-7x_4=3 @\rlap{\hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{-I}$}},
       2x_2-3x_3+ x_4=1 @\rlap{\hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{2}$}}% <- don't omit this comment!!!!
}%
\hphantom{%
  \vbox{%
     %repeat the \hboxes from above:
     %  - probably remove \left.\right. from the boxes this time -
     \hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{-I}$}%
     \hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{-I}$}%
     \hbox{\enspace$\left.\right.{2}$}%
  }%
}%
ZZ
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

A crude attempt without packages:

```latex
\begin{document}

\[%
\left\{%
\begin{array}{@{}*3{r@{\mskip\medmuskip}c@{\mskip\medmuskip}}r@{\mskip\thickmuskip}c@{\mskip\thickmuskip}r|l@{}}
 x_1&+&3x_2&-&4x_3&-&2x_4&=&3&\\
2x_1&+& x_2&-& x_3&-&3x_4&=&2&-I\\
2x_1& &    &+& x_3&-&7x_4&=&3&-I\\
    & &2x_2&-&3x_3&+& x_4&=&1&
\end{array}
\right.%
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]